# Bootstrap: Dropdown won't go on a new line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

[image: Here is how it looks]

I am trying to create a form, but for some reason I can't get multiple dropdowns to display correctly one underneath the other. Here's my code:

```
            <div class="form-group" style="display: block;">
            <label for="step1.1" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Label 1</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                <select name="data[step1][1]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
                        id="step1.1">

                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="x">X</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="display: block;">
            <label for="step1.2" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Label 2</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                <select name="data[step1][2]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
                        id="step1.2">

                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="x">X</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Bootstrap, its Grid system has 12 columns. So to correctly display your dropdown to next row, i.e underneath the other, you have to complete all the 12 row.

In your code, you are using 3 columns (col-md-3) for label and 4 columns (col-md-4) for the select box. So the total is 3+4=7 due to which remaining 5 columns are left. So instead of using col-md-4, use col-md-9 to complete the grid

Here goes the correct code:-

```html
<div class="form-group" style="display: block;">
 <label for="step1.1" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Label 1</label>
 <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
  <select name="data[step1][1]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
   id="step1.1">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="x">X</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="display: block;">
 <label for="step1.2" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Label 2</label>
 <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
  <select name="data[step1][2]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
   id="step1.2">
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="x">X</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 ways you could do it: http://pastebin.com/XivnbbHE

I'm not sure if you wanted the elements inline with each other, or one on top of the other, so I included both. You can use the bootstrap class `inline` or `form-inline` to achieve this. With the first one, the selects are very narrow.  You could fix that will css.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses 12 columns layout, See Bootstrap grid Examples [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

In your case you are using `col-md-3` for label and `col-md-4` for input so this makes 7 grids. You should use `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` or something which complete 12 grids. Same goes for `sm` and `xs`

Try [http://shoelace.io](http://shoelace.io/) to check the grids.